# creating an options menu with quit application function

Tags: java, android

I'm writing an application for android and I would like to insert an options menu, that would have only one function and that is to quit an application.

My options_menu.xml looks like this (I created a new folder under res called menu - just like the instructions said):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/quit"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_quit"
          android:title="@string/quit" />          
</menu>
```

Than I added the following code to my java class file:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.quit:
        finish();
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

I also defined the @string/quit in values - strings.xml file, but it still says that there is an error:

```
C:\Users\Domen\workspace\Lovne Dobe1.1\res\menu\options_menu.xml:3: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'title' with value '@string/quit')
```

So if anybody can help I would be very grateful.

Comment: My options_menu: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/quit"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_quit"
          android:title="@string/quit" />          
</menu>

Comment: Can you show us the contents of your strings.xml?

Answer (score 1):

your strings.xml file should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="quit">Quit</string>
    ...
</resources>
```

Verify it is so.

Answer (score 1):

My string.xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<string name="hello">Hello World, LovneDobe!</string>
<string name="app_name">Lovne dobe</string>
<string name="quit">Quit</string>
<string-array name="zivali_array">
    <item>Alpski svizec</item>
    <item>Damjak</item>
    ...
</string-array>
```

I fixed the string like you said but it's still reporting error. Is says that is an 
Unparsed aapt error(s)! Check the console for output.   Lovne Dobe1.1       Unknown Android Packaging Problem